# Firma Digital XML en C# y/o VB

Tags: c#, vb6, certificado-ssl, firma-digital, siatinfo

necesito su ayuda, soy nuevo en el tema de firma digital, impuestos en Bolivia esta implementando el Sistema de Facturacion Electronica que otros paises ya implementaron, el punto es q me pidieron generar la llave privada y la solicitud de certificado, ellos me devolvieron el certificado de pruebas. ahora tengo que firmar el xml de la factura con dicho certificado. Los archivos tiene las sgtes extensiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he buscado un poco por internet, pero no encontre nada claro, he visto que otros firman con certificados .pfx.

Agradeceria si alguien puede darme una ayuda o compartirme algun link, donde haya algo claro.

Answer (score 1):

Solo para aclarar: .Net no soporta de manera nativa los archivos .pem

Sin embargo, puedes trabajar tu mensaje XML de igual manera con archivos .pem, la diferencia es que con archivos .pem: No podrás firmar tu mensaje XML sin utilizar librería de terceros como ser: [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/), `SecureBlackbox [comercial]` que facilitan las tareas de lectura, validación, encriptación y desencriptado de llaves.

Los archivos .pfx se utilizan para poder trabajar con las librerías nativas del Framework .Net sin utilizar `BouncyCastle` o `SecureBlackbox [comercial]` más adelante te explico cómo se genera el pfx a partir del .pem

Abajo un ejemplo de Lectura de datos con librería de terceros `BouncyCastle` no te olvides de quitar las cabecera y pie del texto de la llave:

```
-----ESTO debes quitar de tu archivo -----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String("la0Cz.....D43g=="); // string a desencriptar, codificada en base64 

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair; 

using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\miLlavePrivada.pem")) // archivo que contiene la llave privada RSA PKCS1 
    keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) new PemReader(reader).ReadObject(); 

var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private); 

var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
```

Para importar fácilmente las llaves privadas `RSA`, sin utilizar librerías de código de terceros tales como `BouncyCastle`, `SecureBlackbox [comercial]`, no se puede únicamente con los archivos .pem como recurso. Para ello debes combinar tu llave `PEM` con la llave privada (`tuarchivo.key`) y el archivo de certificado (`tuarchivo.crt`) para luego obtener el `tuarchivo.pfx` el cual si se puede manejar desde .Net Framework nativamente.

Para generar el archivo PFX desde lineas de comando utiliza [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in a.crt -inkey a.key -export -out a.pfx
```

Luego puedes utilizar este código a continuación:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Certificate2 combinedCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\archivo.pfx");
```

Aquí otro ejemplo de [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) para encriptar y desencriptar utilizando RSACryptoServiceProvider:

Dejo este ejemplo para desencriptar para importar vas a necesitar la clave del PFX y la bandera exportable (ver: BouncyCastle [RSAPrivateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949727/bouncycastle-rsaprivatekey-to-net-rsaprivatekey) to .NET RSAPrivateKey)

```
X509KeyStorageFlags flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("my.pfx", "somepass", flags);

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

Para este nuevo sistema de facturación electrónica el `SIAT` ha dispuesto un sitio con toda la información acerca de estructuras del mensaje que tipo de llaves se utilizan y adicionales:

[Guía de Información de Firmas Digitales](http://siatinfo.impuestos.gob.bo/images/archivos_tecnicos/guias_informes/PresentacionFirmaDigital.pdf)

[Firmado de Archivos XML](http://siatinfo.impuestos.gob.bo/index.php/menu-uno-4/firmado-de-xml)

[Estructura y Mensaje del XML](http://siatinfo.impuestos.gob.bo/index.php/certificacion-de-sistemas/inicio-de-certificacion-2/factura-estandar)

Otra forma de convertir `PEM` a `PFX`

[PEM a PFX](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/pfx_create_from_pem_files.asp)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias, implementare esto y te aviso, no tenia ni idea por donde comenzar, este mismo ejemplo lo implemente en java (http://siatinfo.impuestos.gob.bo/index.php/menu-uno-4/firmado-de-xml) pero no puede firmar, intentare nuevamente y te aviso cualquier cosa, de nuevo gracias

Comment: no te olvides marcar como válida la respuesta. Me avisas cualquier cosa. También estoy implementando lo mismo, soy de Bolivia.

Comment: disculpa estas pudiendo recepcionar factura en los servidores de impuestos?

Comment: en los sitios de prueba si @carlos

Comment: estube buscando como firmar con BouncyCastle, me he guiado de estos blog: [https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190312/295988.html], [https://web.archive.org/web/20140120123730/http://elian.co.uk/post/2009/07/29/Bouncy-Castle-CSharp.aspx], y efectivamente logro firmar un text de prueba, pero lo que no logro es cargar el certificado pem, por favor sera que me podes guiar:

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters

Public Class clsBCEngine
   Private ReadOnly _blockCipher As IBlockCipher
   Private _cipher As PaddedBufferedBlockCipher
   Private _padding As IBlockCipherPadding

   Public Sub New(ByVal blockCipher As IBlockCipher)
      _blockCipher = blockCipher
   End Sub

   Public Sub SetPadding(ByVal padding As IBlockCipherPadding)
      If padding IsNot Nothing Then _padding = padding
   End Sub

   Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plain As String, ByVal key As String) As String
      Dim result As Byte() = BouncyCastleCrypto(True, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plain), key)
      Return Convert.ToBase64String(result)
   End Function

   Public Function Decrypt(ByVal cipher As String, ByVal key As String) As String
      Dim result As Byte() = BouncyCastleCrypto(False, Convert.FromBase64String(cipher), key)
      Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result)
   End Function

   Private Function BouncyCastleCrypto(ByVal forEncrypt As Boolean, ByVal input As Byte(), ByVal key As String) As Byte()
      Try
         _cipher = If(_padding Is Nothing, New PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(_blockCipher), New PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(_blockCipher, _padding))
         Dim keyByte As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
         _cipher.Init(forEncrypt, New KeyParameter(keyByte))
         Return _cipher.DoFinal(input)

      Catch ex As Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.CryptoException
         Throw New CryptoException(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Function
End Class
```

metodo que usa la clase:

```
 Private Function AESEncryptation(ByVal strPlain As String, ByVal strKey As String, ByVal boolFips As Boolean) As String()
      Try
         Dim _padding As Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.IBlockCipherPadding
         Dim pkcs As New Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.Pkcs7Padding()
         _padding = pkcs


         Dim bcEngine As New clsBCEngine(New Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.AesEngine())
         bcEngine.SetPadding(_padding)

         Console.WriteLine("Orginal: " & strPlain)

         Dim strText_Encript = bcEngine.Encrypt(strPlain, strKey)
         Console.WriteLine("Encriptado: " & strText_Encript)

         Dim strText_DesEncript = bcEngine.Decrypt(strText_Encript, strKey)
         Console.WriteLine("Des Encriptado: " & strText_DesEncript)

         Dim boolres = True

      Catch ex As Exception
         Throw ex
      End Try
   End Function
```

probando:

```
Private Sub SFE_FirmaPEM()
      Try
         Dim strKey As String = "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD"
         Dim strText As String = "Esto es una Prueba"

         AESEncryptation(strText, strKey, True)

      Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
      End Try
   End Sub
```

Orginal: Esto es una Prueba

Encriptado: m+1KGk9k8IFYFxSC9a8UTrEl20vE1xJrJp/f+Fpijok=

Des Encriptado: Esto es una Prueba

@jtaborga **Lo que no entiendo es donde deberia cargar el Certificado .Pem**

Comment: modifica la etiqueta de tu pregunta dices que buscas el codigo en C# pero agregas una respuesta en VB

Comment: @MiguelZarate, mil disculpas recien estoy viendo esto de publicar en esta plataforma. agregue una respuesta por que no logre insertar mucho codigo en un comentario asi con sangria y todo eso.